# Are MUH and IIT compatible

Tags: consciousness, universe, platonism, theory-of-mind

I really like Integrated Information Theory (IIT), i just discovered Mathematical universe hypothesis (MUH) i also feel pretty open to this idea i only wonder if there compatible since IIT disproves Computational Theory of Mind (CTM) but a computer programming a brain is also just mathematics and if the universe is made of mathematics and we are conscious in this mathematical universe doesn't that automatically imply CTM?
I know Max Tegmark (founder of MUH) is a small advocate for IIT so i think there compatible i just don't know how.
A small question on the side if we find proof (i think its impossible to find absolute proof of this but lets just accept this for the question) that mathematical forms are real so we discovered math and didn't create it would this also imply MUH or is it possible that mathematical forms exist but that that doesn't automatically imply MUH.

Kind regards jeroen.

Comment: I like the *idea* of IIT, finding an empirical criterion for occurring of consciousness. But [as Aaronson showed](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=1799), IIT itself is hopeless. It makes matrix multipliers and logic gates joined into expander graphs "conscious", among other things. This said, Tegmark wrote a paper [Improved Measures of Integrated Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02626), so presumably he considers the idea compatible with MUH. It makes sense, if the universe is "made of  math" there should be a mathematical characteristic standing for consciousness too.

Comment: please document your acronysms, not everybody knows what CTM stands for. Use of jargon should be limited to the necessary minimum.

Comment: @Conifold And what basis do you have for your apparent conviction that matrix multipliers are not to some small degree conscious? That is just the fallacy of appeal to the stone. Panpsychism is a perfectly valid perspective. Nothing about qualia requires that they be attached to complex human thoughts.

Comment: @causative According to IIT, they are not conscious "to small degree", the II can be made arbitrarily high.

Comment: @Conifold For an arbitrarily large matrix, sure. Note that ChatGPT or any other giant neural network is mostly an "arbitrarily large matrix multiplication" (plus activation functions, which are only a small fraction of what the network is doing) and can do some amazing things. Anyway are you saying your only objection is to the *degree* of consciousness assigned to the matrix multiplier, and not to its mere presence?

Comment: @causative It is Aaronson's objection, I am not claiming credit. It is that we wanted a test that would single out recognizably "conscious" things using some measurable characteristic. A test that overwhelmingly outputs false positives with a suggestion that we should re-adjust what "conscious" means to match it is the opposite of how empirical theories are supposed to work. II may well pick out something important (itself), but as a measure of what was intended it fails miserably. It is like proposing pressure as a measure of heat and then saying that this is what "heat" should mean instead.

Comment: @Conifold (1) You didn't answer my question. (2) You repeated and endorsed Aaronson's objection so you have made it your own, which creates a duty for you to justify what you believe. (3) Empirical theories should match our actual observations, not our preconceptions. "Simple systems aren't conscious" is a preconception, not an observation. The investigator cannot observe the presence or absence of consciousness in any system except the investigator's own individual consciousness. If you do believe simple systems aren't conscious, you have given no reason besides appeal to the stone in support

Comment: @causative Empirical theories should match observations, not explain the mismatch by "preconceptions" and contrive definitions to "match" what they got. What was asked is a test that correlates with empirical manifestations of "consciousness" (we do not detect it in others by introspection), not some "secret consciousness" of panpsychism. What was delivered is Lorentz's elusive aether with "explanation" why the aether wind is not there. Moreover, we do not have independent reasons to believe that what IIT declares conscious is. In other words, its "test" is circular regardless of conceptions.

Comment: @Conifold It's a little unclear what you're saying here but I'm getting the impression you think there are "empirical manifestations" of consciousness that IIT doesn't agree with, and that specifically, you think the non-consciousness of simple systems is an "empirical manifestation." But this simply is false; what scientific instrument is there that could produce a measurement showing a simple system is not conscious? That's what an "empirical manifestation" would mean. We're right back where we started and you haven't addressed the point.

Comment: @causative Turn the question around. What "scientific instrument" measurements does IIT have to match its II calculations to? If there are none then why associate them with "consciousness" as opposed to "intelligence", "complexity", "*elan vital*" or some other vague colloquial term and pretend that it relates something to something else?

Comment: @Conifold The measurements IIT matches are our direct introspective experience of consciousness. All a theory of consciousness must do is match those, as well as any other physical measurements that might be relevant to the theory, and be sufficiently simple in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @causative I am not sure how our "direct introspective experience of consciousness" delivers something to be matched to integrated information, or even distinguishes consciousness from a host of other phenomena, like intelligence, mental processing capacity, etc. But aside from that, how is the right theory supposed to be distinguishable from a wrong one that produces pervasive false positives in cases where "direct introspective experience" is not available? Which is almost everywhere.

Comment: @Conifold (1) What specific features of introspective experience IIT matches would be a lengthy discussion outside the scope of this. (2) We don't know if they are true positives or false positives, because direct introspective experience is not available. For what we cannot observe, as with any scientific theory, we must trust to Occam's razor. Which is to say that if the simplest theory (that matches our observations) makes a prediction X, and we have no direct observations of X, our best move is to trust what the theory states about X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- IIT is essentially a flavor of **physical monism**. It presupposes that what we typically think of as the mental--consciousness--is a manifestation of a physical state. That, in itself, is not unusual. It's a controversial idea, but one shared by many currently debated theories. What makes IIT unique is that it claims to have discovered the mathematical relationship between the complexity of information maintained in a physical structure and the level of consciousness it generates. A highly complex structure like the human brain generates a high level of consciousness, and according to IIT, those two things are not merely related, they are in fact two views of the same thing. It would be an overreach to say that IIT "disproves" CTM, they are more like rival versions of the same goal--to explain consciousness in a purely physicalist manner.
- MUH, on the other hand, is a flavor of **ideal monism**. It conjectures that what we usually think of as the physical is actually a manifestation of something non-physical: Mathematical structures. This is a bit hard to conceptualize, so it might be easiest to think of the experience of a video game. The game world looks and sounds real. It apparently has physical objects in it, and those objects seem to have physical interactions. But at root, that entire world is just made up of the 1s and 0s of computer programming. Similarly, it's conceivable that our entire universe could also be a simulation. All the physical laws could be just the results of mathematical calculations. (This idea, up to this point, is the subject of Bostrom's Simulation Theory.) However, if the world could be a simulation, created mathematically on a computer, then perhaps it could also just be a purely mathematical object itself. There are mathematical structures, such as irrational numbers like pi, and fractals like the Mandelbrot Set, that are infinitely complex. **Is there a mathematical object so complex it contains the entire universe within it?** That idea is the basis of MUH. There's really no necessary relationship, either positive or negative, between MUH and CTM (the simulation discussed above was just a metaphor, MUH does not require or imply that the world is simulated on a computer).

Superficially, these theories seem incompatible, since one is physicalist, and one is idealist. However, since they operate on different levels of scale, **one could conceivably fit inside the other**. Through IIT we could reduce mind to physics and through MUH we could reduce physics to mathematics. In other words, consciousness might just be a physical structure, but that physical structure itself might be just a portion of mathematical object. Similarly, you could also fit CTM inside MUH if you wanted to.

Arguably, however, if you're going that far, you might just as well return to a **Berkeleyan idealism, or a panentheism**, which states that the entire universe is maintained within the mind of God. That has the advantage over the IIT/MUH merger in as much as it actually has an explanation for consciousness rather than just predictions about it.

It's worth noting that these are all just **speculative, metaphysical theories** at this point. They aren't proven, and they don't prove anything. IIT makes some testable predictions, but they certainly aren't ones powerful enough to certify the theory as a whole.

Comment: What you bring up about the video game is what confuses me since a computer just does maths and IIT would refute that whatever the video game simulates it wouldn't be conscious because phi isn't the same size as that of a brain (that's what I like about IIT), but can we still have phi if everything is maths for example would a computer simulation still not be conscious inside MUH since it doesn't have the same phi even though a computer also just does maths? (hope u understand what i mean since i don't really know how to formulate it in a sentence)

Comment: I have edited, hopefully to explain better.

Comment: I really like this answer and i think we're close to the answer of my question but my question is more of can the universe be mathematical but not allow for simulation hypothesis, can MUH be true but without CTM since IIT refutes CTM it would say that if a computer simulates a brain the brain wouldnt be conscious (the computer itself could be conscious to a degree but that doesnt depend on what it simulates) but a computer does mathematics and if the universe is mathematics could IIT still stand so the mathematical formula of the computer contains phi but what it simulates doesnt

Comment: btw i hope im not anoying you but i really like the style of how you answer my questions and you're already really helping me out so thanks a lot.(Also thanks for introducing me to Berkeleyan idealism since im a christian i really like that way of explaining the universe true god)

Comment: Hey Chris i would love if you could answer my last question so i can close this post with a full answer, if not also please let me know so that i at least could close it knowing i dont have to wait for a response. Kind regards jeroen

Comment: "can MUH be true but without CTM since IIT refutes CTM" I'm not sure that accepting IIT rules out a CTM. In fact, IIT simply is a theory that explains and measures consciousness by positing [neural reentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentry_(neural_circuitry)) and some math to go along with it. The question of [neural computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_computation) is an entirely different question because it asks, are neurons computational or not. Under a [theory of physical computation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/), if neurons compute...

Comment: then brains compute and the CTM applies. In fact, if one were to advance MUH as a hypothesis (I personally think it's pseudoscientific), then having a CTM based on neural computation would be the only explanation of how mathematical structure can describe neural behavior, though one could try to argue that neurons as a [dynamical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) might somehow be a distinct form of computation since it strives for an analog description of brain state. (To be clear, there is no empirical evidence to support MUH, and it is metaphysically speculative).

Comment: @Jeroen - with the help of JD's comments, I created a more complete answer, please see if this addresses your questions.

Comment: Thank you it really did. You have a amazing way of explaining this, its a great talent. kind regards jeroen.

Answer (score 1):

MUH states that the ontological representation of reality IS mathematics. IIT on the other hand accepts the traditional view that consciousness is grounded on physical matter, but instead of trying to explain how consciousness comes out of physical matter, goes the other way by trying to infer this physical foundation based on the behaviour of consciousness by reduction using mathematics.

**So, in IIT mathematics are used as a tool to infer reality, while in MUH mathematics IS the reality.**